# Try and Except exceptions with a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, try-except

Let's say I asked the user for a word, if the word is not a key in the dictionary, then I want to print "That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again". How would I do this using try and except? This is what I have so far.

```
dict = {"These": 1, "are": 2, "words": 3}
while True:
    try:
        w = input("Enter a word: ")
    except: 
        print("That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again")
    else:
        print("That word is a key in the dictionary")
```

Comment: Do you have to use try except? There are other better ways.

Comment: why not try to check only using in, example:

"w in dict"

by the way, dont use dict it's a reserved word

Comment: @sP_ No, I don't have to, but I'd like to know if using try and except is possible.

Comment: @LeonardoFabioOrozcoPadilla `dict` is not a "reserved word", its simply the name of an existing type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could catch the `KeyError` when accessing a key that doesn't exist in the map:

```
try:
    w = input("Enter a word: ")
    k[w]
except KeyError:
    print("That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again")
else:
    print("That word is a key in the dictionary")
```

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer your question, this code does what you're looking for:

```
words = {"these": 1, "are": 2, "words": 3}
while True:
    try:
        value = words[input("Enter a word: ").trim().lower()]
    except KeyError: 
        print("That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again")
    else:
        print("That word is a key in the dictionary")
```

Couple important things to call out. Using `except:` without an `Exception` is very bad practice, as it will catch anything (like [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) or [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) for instance, which will prevent your program from exiting correctly). `dict` is a name of a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict), so you are re-defining it by naming your dictionary `dict`.

As others suggested in the comments, you don't need try/except to do this unless you're trying to learn more about try/except. A better way to do this would be to use a set:

```
words = {"these", "are", "words"}
while True:
    if words[input("Enter a word: ").trim().lower()] in words:
        print("That word is a key in the dictionary")
    else:
        print("That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also avoid using try/except blocks by using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which returns the value mapped at the specified key, or `None`(default) if the key was not found. You can change this default to anything you want.

**Code:**

```
data = {"These": 1, "are": 2, "words": 3}

# make all keys lowercase
data = {k.lower(): v for k, v in data.items()}

while True:
    w = input("Enter a word: ")

    if data.get(w.lower()):
        print("That word is a key in the dictionary")
    else:
        print("That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a word: these
That word is a key in the dictionary
Enter a word: These
That word is a key in the dictionary
Enter a word: blah
That word is not a key in the dictionary, try again
```

**Note:** Keys above were converted to lowercase to avoid case insensitivity when looking up keys. You also shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name, since it shadows the reserved keyword.